# How to discard repetition structure in for each loop in XSLt 2.0.

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I need to map a repetitive structure to a single field in the output xml in such a way that if **Success** Case matches, only the required field should be mapped and In the Alternate scenario, that field should be made empty in the outgoing request. 
 I am facing trouble in handling the **Success Flow** and **Alternate flow**.

**Success Case Input:**

```
<Message>
<MessageName>Hello World</MessageName>  
<Data>
    <Partner>
        <PartnerType>A</PartnerType>
        <ParnterId>01</ParnterId>
    </Partner>
    <Partner>
        <PartnerType>B</PartnerType>
        <ParnterId>02</ParnterId>
    </Partner>
    <Partner>
        <PartnerType>C</PartnerType>
        <ParnterId>03</ParnterId>
    </Partner>
    <Partner>
        <PartnerType>D</PartnerType>
        <ParnterId>04</ParnterId>
    </Partner>
</Data>

</Message>
```

**Success Case Expected Output:**

```
<Request>
<RequestName>Hello World</RequestName>  
<PartnerAIdentifier>01</PartnerAIdentifier>
</Request>
```

**Success Case Current Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request>
   <RequestName>Hello World</RequestName>
   <PartnerAIdentifier>01</PartnerAIdentifier>
   <PartnerAIdentifier/>
   <PartnerAIdentifier/>
   <PartnerAIdentifier/>
</Request>
```

**Alternate Case Input:**

```
<Message>
<MessageName>Hello World</MessageName>  
<Data>

    <Partner>
        <PartnerType>B</PartnerType>
        <ParnterId>02</ParnterId>
    </Partner>
    <Partner>
        <PartnerType>C</PartnerType>
        <ParnterId>03</ParnterId>
    </Partner>
    <Partner>
        <PartnerType>D</PartnerType>
        <ParnterId>04</ParnterId>
    </Partner>
</Data>

</Message>
```

**Alternate Case Expected Output:**

```
<Request>
<RequestName>Hello World</RequestName>  
<PartnerAIdentifier></PartnerAIdentifier>
</Request>
```

**Alternate Case Current Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request>
   <RequestName>Hello World</RequestName>
   <PartnerAIdentifier/>
   <PartnerAIdentifier/>
   <PartnerAIdentifier/>
</Request>
```

**My XSLt:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/Message">
        <Request>
        <RequestName>
            <xsl:value-of select="MessageName" />
        </RequestName>
        <xsl:for-each select="Data/Partner">

            <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="PartnerType ='A'">
             <PartnerAIdentifier>
               <xsl:value-of select="ParnterId" />
             </PartnerAIdentifier>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
            <PartnerAIdentifier>
            </PartnerAIdentifier>
            </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>


        </xsl:for-each>



        </Request>

        </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Problem:**
If the Input request have a Partner element with type A, then it's Identifier should be mapped to outgoing request, and if the input request does not contain that Partner element then an single empty field should be made. But since I have to  use "for-each" , So is there any additional logic which I can use to discard the repetition structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want one `PartnerAIdentifier` output, there is no need to use an `xsl:for-each` here. You can put the test condition on the `PartnerType` in a single `xsl:value-of`

```
<xsl:value-of select="Data/Partner[PartnerType='A']/ParnterId" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/Message">
        <Request>
            <RequestName>
                <xsl:value-of select="MessageName" />
            </RequestName>
             <PartnerAIdentifier>
               <xsl:value-of select="Data/Partner[PartnerType='A']/ParnterId" />
             </PartnerAIdentifier>
        </Request>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So, if there is no `PartnerType` then the `PartnerAIdentifier` will be empty as required.